# BaseAdapter and SectionIndexer on ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I wrote an BaseAdapter which implement the SectionIndexer interface and all work fine, I can switch my index section using the setFastScrollingEnabled(true) of my ListView, the only issues is that the box of my letter index, which normally (in the Contacts app for example) are displayed in the bottom center of the screen, are displayed at the left top corner and drew with the color white: can I customize the position of the letter box?

Thanks in advance.

pedr0

Answer (score 0):

pedr0, please check if your problem is the same reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9054

Comment: I saw that, it is a current issues :-( Thanks!